# renderAs="PDF" attribute getting this error--->"PDF generation failed. Check the page markup is valid"

Tags: visualforce

I was created v.f with tables &images.now looks fine but after adding renderAs="PDF" attribute getting this error--->"PDF generation failed. Check the page markup is valid" Please check and do needfull thanks in advance.

Below is the code.

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" sidebar="false" renderAs="PDF" >
<apex:form >
   <apex:image url="{!$Resource.form}" width="100%" height="100%">
   </apex:image>
       <table>
            <tr></tr>
            <tr></tr>
            <tr></tr>
        </table>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>QUALITY OF SERVICE</b>
        <table>
            <tr></tr>
            <tr></tr>
            <tr></tr>
        </table>    
        <table>  
        <style>
        {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    }
     border="1" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10">
          <tr>
          <th> Area</th>
          <th> Cretirea</th>
          <th> Rating(1 to 4)</th>
          </tr>
            <tr>
            <th>staff Arability </th>
            <td>how easy are we contact and is staff available to you at times the that you require support? </td>
            <td> </td>
            </tr>
               <tr>
                <th>technical support</th>
                 <td>what do you think of our level of technical support in relation to work performed?</td>
                 <td></td>
               </tr>
                   <tr>
                   <td colspan="1">comments (if any)</td>
                   </tr>
                   </style>
      </table>    

                   <br/>

                   &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>QUALITY OF WORK PERFORMED</b><br/>
                   <table>
                        <tr></tr>
                        <tr></tr>
                        <tr></tr>
                   </table>
                        <table border="1" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10">
                           <tr>
                           <th> Area</th>
                           <th> Cretirea</th>
                           <th> Rating(1 to 4)</th>
                           </tr>
                              <tr>
                              <th>Quality Standard</th>
                              <td>How would you rate the quality of the work perfomed and does it meet your criteria standards?</td>
                              <td></td>
                              </tr>
                                 <tr>
                                 <th>Test Report</th>
                                 <td>how would you describe our test reports,are they clear and do they contain sufficient detail?</td>
                                 <td></td>
                                 </tr>
                                 <tr>
                                 <td>Comments (if any)</td>
                                 </tr>

                           </table><br/>
                             &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>OTHER</b><br/>
                             <table>
                                <tr></tr>
                                <tr></tr>
                                <tr></tr>
                            </table> 
                                      <table  border="1" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10">
                                         <tr>
                                         <th> Area</th>
                                         <th> Cretirea</th>
                                         <th> Rating(1 to 4)</th>
                                         </tr>
                                             <tr>
                                             <th>price</th>
                                             <td>How do our prices compare with other sub-contractor</td>
                                             <td></td>
                                             </tr>
                                                 <tr>
                                                 <td>Status Quo</td>
                                                 <td>How would you rate your level of satisfication to 
                                                 continue with Els as service provider</td>
                                                 <td></td>
                                                 </tr>
                                                      <tr>
                                                      <td>Recommandetion</td>
                                                      <td>How would your describe your level of 
                                                      compfort recommending ELS to another organization?</td>
                                                      <td></td>
                                                      </tr>
                                                            <tr>
                                                            <td>Delivery</td>
                                                            <td>How do our delivery compare with other 
                                                            sub-contractor?</td> 
                                                            <td></td>
                                                            </tr> 
                                                                 <tr>
                                                                 <td>comments (if any)</td>
                                                                 </tr>


                                       </table>
                                       <br/><br/><br/>

                                                                     <b>Your Sign and Stamp</b>
                                                                          <apex:image url="{!$Resource.bottom}" width="1370" height="30">
                                                                          </apex:image>



</apex:form>      
</apex:page>
```

Comment: You really need to, at the very least, post your code. Explaining what you've done to try and resolve it yourself will also help. Otherwise you'll simply never get an answer.

Comment: This may help http://sfdcsrini.blogspot.com/2015/01/visualforce-pdf-rendering.html

Comment: and you also spelled "criteria" and "comfort" incorrectly.

Comment: Please give correct solution its not working..

Answer (score 0):

Because your markup is not correct...

Take this for example:

```
<style>
        {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    }
     border="1" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10">
```

**WHAT IT THAT** You have a style in the middle of a table, no opening < or tag name before the border="1" etc.

Check your markup and ensure it is correct.

Comment: please give correct solution its not working...